# how to generate code coverage report for androidTest using Jacoco in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, jacoco

I am able to generate code coverage report using Jacoco for test folder and I also want to generate report for instrument testcase in androidTest folder. Please share any code snippet or link to refer.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link](http://blog.houzz.com/post/158160064293/android-code-coverage-with-jacoco) to an article that I wrote about code coverage with Android instrument test case.

Comment: and facing issue with Dagger2 library here I have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714259/error-when-generating-code-coverage-report-for-androidtest-instrumented-testcase can please help on this